# Mondoarchive, can I slow down write speed, and can I have it take less cpu resources?

Tags: linux, backup

I want to backup a remote webserver live using mondoarchive, but it takes too much cpu and bandwidth which results in web requests timeout.

Can I have it slow down write speed and make it take less cpu, regardless if its slower to backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [nice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) and [ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) which allow you to set a lower process priority (for cpu and disk scheduling, respectively).

Example usage:

```
ionice -c 3 nice mondoarchive -optionA -optionB
```

If necessary, you can also change the priority of an already running backup using ionice (for disk priority) and renice (for cpu priority).